# In Apache httpd server, is it possible to define a section of httpd.conf that will apply to *all* VirtualHosts?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm slowly learning more about Apache HTTPD server, but I'm still mostly a newbie.

Recently, I've been working on tightening up security, by adding headers to a VirtualHost.  But, if I have an httpd.conf with (say) 10 VirtualHost definitions, is it necessary to add the same header(s) to all 10 VirtualHost definitions?

Is it possible to have a section of httpd.conf (or a separate .conf file that will be included in all VirtualHost definitions, without having to individually add the header to each VirtualHost definition?

So, is it possible, instead of doing:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my@myorg.com
    ServerName  www.myorg.com
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my@myorg.com
    ServerName  www2.myorg.com
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin my@myorg.com
    ServerName  www.myorg.com
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 H+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/httpd/conf/ssl_certs/nitssolutions.com/nitssol1_cert.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/httpd/conf/ssl_certs/nitssolutions.com/nitssol1_key.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile    /etc/httpd/conf/ssl_certs/nitssolutions.com/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin my@myorg.com
    ServerName  www2.myorg.com
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/httpd/conf/ssl_certs/nitssolutions.com/nitssol1_cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/httpd/conf/ssl_certs/nitssolutions.com/nitssol1_key.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile    /etc/httpd/conf/ssl_certs/nitssolutions.com/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible to define a section of httpd.conf (or an include file of httpd.conf), where I can put these headers and other directives *once* and have them apply to *all* VirtualHost definitions?

Something like:
specific section of httpd.conf:

```
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 H+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
```

And then when I define a VirtualHost, I just do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@myorg.com
    ServerName  www.myorg.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin me@myorg.com
    ServerName  www.myorg.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This way, I can define (and, in the future, change) my security related directives in one place, and not have to make adjustments in 5 or 10 or 20 or more places?

Possible?

Comment: Have a look at mod_macro (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_macro.html).  Dynamic mass vhost might be of help as well (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/mass.html).  But more general, see this: https://serverfault.com/questions/834349/does-apache2-have-a-way-of-setting-global-vhosts, global configurations apply to all.

Comment: Very cool!  Thanks, Nic!  (If you answer, I'll accept it.)

Comment: Thanks.  Done as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple options.

Option 1: configuration in the global context (outside any VirtualHost) applies to them all.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/834349/does-apache2-have-a-way-of-setting-global-vhosts

Option 2: mod_macro.  You can configure macros to simplify the multi-configuration.  See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_macro.html

Option 3: dynamic mass VirtualHost configurations.  Here you use wildcards.  See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/mass.html

Comment: Thanks again!  I've been playing with mod_macro, and so far, it's working great!